# SQL join on similar values

Tags: sql, join

I need to join to tables e.g. A and B. In both tables we have column with `first name` and `last name`.

But in table A we can have a `Matthew Smith` while in table B can be the name incorrect `Matthw Smith`. It´s only stupid mistake, but I need to join the tables, when the name is almost equal, e.g. the values are equal for 95%.

Can you help me with that?

Comment: which db you are using ?

Comment: which db schema are you using?

Comment: Using your one example, I calculate `Matthw Smith` to be 92% 'similar' to `Matthew Smith` because 12 out of 13 characters are 'correct'. May I suggest you need to come up with a better definition of 'almost equal', with more test cases. P.S. if you cannot define 'almost equal' as rows in a table then SQL is probably not the language to do this in.

Answer (score 1):

In sqlServer  you can use soundex and difference  function

```
select your_column 
from table_a
join table_b on soundex(a.firstname) = soundex(b.firstname)
and difference(a.firstname, b.firstname) =4 ;
```

(difference 0=4  mean that the two string are very similar)